# Calculating efficiency

Tags: calculus

Say I have 2 guys working together making boats. One of them has to continually produce cabins while the other one continually produces hulls.

Say it takes guy 1 10 hours to create a hull, and 9 to create a cabin.
Guy 2 on the other hand, takes 12 hours to create a hull and 10 to create a cabin.

How do I find out who should be on which position?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario $(1,2) = (H,C)$:

- Every $10$ hours they will complete a boat.

Scenario $(1,2) = (C,H)$:

- Every $12$ hours they will complete a boat, with every three completed boats there will be an additional cabin created.

What is better depends on how much you can profit from a completed boat, and what to do with surplus cabins? My guess is that scenario 1 is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Relative costs are relavant here.

Guy 1 has relative costs of $\frac{10}{9} \text{hulls}$ for one cabin.

Guy 2 has relative costs of $\frac{12}{10} \text{hulls}$ for one cabin.

The guy, who has lower relative costs should produce cabins.

---

Guy 1 has relative costs of $\frac{9}{10} \text{cabins}$ for one hull.

Guy 2 has relative costs of $\frac{10}{12} \text{cabins}$ for one hull.

The guy, who has lower relative costs should produce hulls.